# Are there at present any passenger rail services between Poland and Belarus?

Tags: trains, poland, belarus

Are there at present any passenger rail services between Poland and Belarus? I'm mostly interested in the (Warsaw -) Terespol - Brest (- Minsk) services, but information about other railway border checkpoints are also welcome. Not too long ago, there used to be countless services, now I couldn't find any, but I also couldn't find any source stating they were cancelled or suspended...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems there isn't. Here's the obligatory link to [Seat 61](https://www.seat61.com/international-trains/trains-from-Warsaw.htm#Warsaw_to_Minsk), on the Warsaw - Minsk section.

> Train currently suspended due to Covid-19 and now sanctions & the war in Ukraine.